# How can I move my MS Office license to a new Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office, license

I have purchased a new 64-bit iMac and would like to move my version of Office for Mac 11 to it from my older iMac that is a 32-bit machine.

How do I uninstall so that I may use my existing validation codes on my new iMac?

Answer (score 1):

I had installed office on a second mac, and when I accidentally opened the first copy while the second was open.

I got an error message: "this copy of office is open on a different computer on your network" a bit creepy, but that was my reminder to delete he first copy.

(Fortunately, Open Office has no such issue.)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to **System Preferences.app > Security and Privacy** and block incoming connections to Word you will be able to use your license on another mac.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click Security and Privacy
3. Click "Firewall"
4. Click "Firewall Options"
5. Select "Block incoming connections" from the drop down next to Microsoft Word.app
   [image]
   [image]
   If you want to uninstall, just delete the Microsoft Word.app from the Microsoft folder within `/Applications`. This will also allow you to use your license again.